# Add text file NAMES to fields in a dbf

Tags: python, arcgis, dbf

I want to populate 2 fields of a dbf table with the names of several text files in a directory.

For example:

```
My_Dog_Named_Spot_02.txt
```

DBF reads:

```
Field1: My_Dog_Named_Spot
Field2: 02
```

Is there a way to do this using Python code?

Comment: List the files in the directory and `split` each file's name in two. I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: Are you using an existing `dbf` file, or creating a new one?  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm about to start testing. It's an existing dbf- actually a table in a file geodatabase.

Comment: I need to add several of these txt file names into the tables. Apologies for the dumb question- I don't have much experience with python or code. I mostly work within the ArcGIS tools/interface

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can use `os.glob('some/dir/with/files/*.txt')` to get a listing of text files, and [dbf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) to create/use a dbf and store the results:

```
import dbf
import os

with dbf.Table('some_dbf') as files:
    for filename in os.glob('*.txt')
        base, number = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0].rsplit('_', 1)
        files.append((base, number)) # assuming field1 and field2 are the first two fields
```

Answer (score -1):

something like this:

```
import os

with open('out.dbf', 'w') as od:

    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(some_directory):
        for fn in files:
            (base, ext) = os.path.splitext(fn)
            if ext == '.txt':
                toks = base.split('_')
                od.write('Field1: ' + '_'.join(toks[:-1]))
                od.write('Field2: ' + toks[-1])

od.close()
```